# How to create a list of links and divs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, hyperlink

I wish to create divs, contents of the div, put those each in an  tag, and then assign links the to the  with JavaScript.

I apologize in advance for the inception of my situation.

This is what the interior of the sidebar looks like right now:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <a href="link.a"><div>item a</div></a>
  <a href="link.b"><div>item b</div></a>
  <a href="link.c"><div>item c</div></a>
</div>
```

I want to create the inside the "sidebar" div using two arrays:

```
var linkList = ["link.a", "link.b", "link.c"];
var titleList = ["item a", "item b", "item c"];
```

I want the final html code to look like this:

```
<div id="sidebar" onload="createLinks()">
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to code the JavaScript to make this work. If someone could help me, that'd be great!

Comment: the onload will not work like this, since it's not available on a div element.

Comment: Okay, is there a different way to approach it?

Comment: You could either take the onload onto the body element, listen for the load event in your script or mark your script with defer.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through one array using `forEach()` and add html using `insertAdjacentHTML`.

**Note**: As some users mentioned in comments `onload` can't be used on the elements. You could either call the function inside `window.onload` or just put `<script>` in the end of `<body>`

```js
var linkList = ["link.a", "link.b", "link.c"];
var titleList = ["item a", "item b", "item c"];

let sidebar = document.querySelector('#sidebar');

linkList.forEach((x,i) => {
  sidebar.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",`<a href="${x}"><div>${titleList[i]}</div></a>`)
})
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
```